# Sparkle fails to update a sandboxed app

Tags: macos, sandbox, sparkle

Can Sparkle be used to update a sandboxed app? The update initially appears to work, giving appropriate user dialog to prompt for the update and doing the copy. However it hangs at the end of the "Installing update...". I notice the following in the console log.

```
Sparkle: Failed to release quarantine on <path to my>.app with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to remove file quarantine on Autoupdate.app.}

2016-02-22 4:52:44.000 PM kernel[0]: exec of <...Path...>/Sparkle/Autoupdate.app/Contents/MacOS/Autoupdate denied since it was quarantined by Anytune Mac and created without user consent, qtn-flags was 0x00000006
```

Other posts have referred to this problem, but they are over 2 years old and I haven't been able to find any current documentation on how to make this work.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the other posts are still correct: the Sparkle developers intend to add some support for this, but it's taking a very long time.

Comment: I saw the previous post, but it was from 4 years ago and the last update was 2 years ago. A lot has changed and I couldn't find anything more current. I guess, sadly, the answer seems to be it still isn't supported.

Comment: The same Github issue that was mentioned in some of those posts is still open, and actually has some recent activity: https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/issues/363

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff for the link. I hadn't seen the recent (almost a year ago) reference to [Sam Dean's branch](https://github.com/samdeane/Sparkle/tree/sandboxing)  I will investigate that branch further. Hopefully this will be rolled into the main Sparkle branch at some point though.